# How to exclude an external js from a particular node?

Tags: 7, javascript

How can we remove an external js from a particular node!

For Ex:
Remove `http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js` from home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script is added in a correct way(using Drupal API) you should be able to unset it as following:

***Drupal 7:***

```
/**
 * Implements HOOK_js_alter().
 *
 * @param $js
 */
function HOOK_js_alter(&$js) {

  $node = menu_get_object();
  if (!empty($node->nid) && $node->nid == XXX) {
    unset($js['your_path']);
  }

}
```

***Drupal 8:***

```
/**
 * Implements HOOK_page_attachments_alte().
 *
 * @param $attachments
 */
function HOOK_page_attachments_alter(&$attachments) {
  /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $source */
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface && $node->id() == XXX) {
    unset($attachments['your_js_path']);
  }
}
```